# Sorting bibliography citation lists for SIAM submissions

Tags: bibliographies, citing, templates

I am working on a document that needs to be prepared with the [SIAM template.](https://www.siam.org/Publications/Journals/About-SIAM-Journals/Information-for-Authors#SIAM-Macros) Currently, my citations appear out of order, such as [2,1,14,3], because they are organized alphabetically in the bibliography, but listed out of order in the \cite{} command.

I know that if I include \usepackage[sort]{natbib} into the preamble of an ordinary document, this would fix things. However, this seems to break the SIAM template. Is there a way that I can fix this, without fixing each line by hand, or (somehow) writing a macro that goes through the document after compilation and replaces all instances of strings of the for [a_1, ..., a_n] with their sorted version?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It appears that adding `\usepackage[sort]{cite}` to the preamble works.